# How to index the same char in different locations correctly

Tags: python, string, list, loops, indexing

I was writing a program to loop through a string and index the capital letters in the string, but it keeps returning the first index of a same character

example:

AbcDeFgAiJ

will return

[0, 3, 5, 0, 9] instead of [0, 3, 5, 7, 9]

here is the code

```
def capitals(word):
    arr = []
    for i in word:
        if i.isupper():
            arr.append(word.index(i))
    return arr
```

Comment: This is a sort of mistake I see fairly often - inside a block of code where you're iterating over a collection (`for i in word`) you call something that operates on the entire collection (`word.index(i)`). It's rarely correct for those two styles to mix in the same chunk of code. Usually solutions that use the latter are cleaner, but you almost never want to use both. Just something to watch out for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.index` will return first index found, so when you have for example two `A` in your string, it will return the index of first `A`.

Try to use `enumerate()` instead:

```py
word = "AbcDeFgAiJ"

out = [idx for idx, ch in enumerate(word) if ch.isupper()]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```